# why every item(use PureComponent) re-render when list change in apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo

I use `React` + `Apollo` now.

I update list by `update` in `immutability-helper`.

when I push some items to list, and found every item(extends PureComponent and have key) run re-render.

// list

```
list.map(edge => (
    <div key={edge.node.id} className="xxxx">
        <Item {...edge.node} />
    </div>
))
```

// Item

```
class Item extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        const { id, title ...otherProps } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
              // ....
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`PureComponent` use shallowEqual. Apollo's data is immutable.

why Pre-existing items run re-render?

Comment: i creat new [issue](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2380#issuecomment-421035371) in react-apollo